# How to get the test case results from script?

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, automated-tests

I use matlab script to create test file(include test suite and test case) in test manager.And when I finished my test,I need use the results of test.If the test cases all passed then exit code is 0;If one of test cases failed then exit code is 1. I want to realize it in my script.

My matlab version is 2016b.
Below is my script:

```
try
    %some code to create my test cases in test manager.I didn't post here.

    ro = run(ts); %run the test suite
    saveToFile(tf); %save the test file

    % Get the results set object from Test Manager
    result = sltest.testmanager.getResultSets;
    % Export the results set object to a file
    sltest.testmanager.exportResults(result,'C:\result.mldatx');

    % Clear results from Test Manager
    sltest.testmanager.clearResults;
    % Close Test Manager
    sltest.testmanager.close;


    %-----This part is what I want to achieve my goal----
    totalfailures = 0;
    totalfailures = sum(vertcat(ro(:).Failed));   
    if totalfailures == 0
        exit(0); 
    else
        exit(1);
    end
    %----------but it couldn't work----------------------


catch e
    disp(getReport(e,'extended'));
    exit(1);
end
exit(totalfailures>0);
```

I check my exit status in Jenkins is 0,But I make a failed test in test file.So it supposed to be 1.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using the MATLAB Unit Test Framework to run tests and get the test results. This will give you a results object that you can easily query to control the exit code for your MATLAB. If you were to run your Simulink Test files thus:

```
import matlab.unittest.TestRunner
import matlab.unittest.TestSuite
import sltest.plugins.TestManagerResultsPlugin

try
    suite = TestSuite.fromFolder('<path to folder with Simulink Tests>');
    % Create a typical runner with text output
    runner = TestRunner.withTextOutput();
    % Add the Simulink Test Results plugin and direct its output to a file
    sltestresults = fullfile(getenv('WORKSPACE'), 'sltestresults.mldatx');
    runner.addPlugin(TestManagerResultsPlugin('ExportToFile', sltestresults));
    % Run the tests
    results = runner.run(suite);
    display(results);
catch e
    disp(getReport(e,'extended'));
    exit(1);
end
exit(any([results.Failed]));
```

That should do the trick. You can modify this additionally to save off the testsuite or testcase as you like.

You can also consider using the matlab.unittest.plugins.TAPPlugin which integrates nicely with Jenkins to publish TAP format test results. There is MathWorks documentation available on all of the plugins and other APIs mentioned here. Here's a nice article telling you how to leverage the MATLAB Unit Test Framework to run Simulink Tests: https://www.mathworks.com/help/sltest/ug/tests-for-continuous-integration.html

Also, MathWorks has released a Jenkins MATLAB Plugin recently that might be helpful to you: https://plugins.jenkins.io/matlab

Hope this helps!

Comment: Anjana,Thanks for your answer! I have check the documentation and I found that in R2016b the number of failed test is NumFailed , not Failed.so I rewrite my script : 
`totalfailures = sum(vertcat(ro(:).NumFailed));` and it could work!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the log in Jenkins to see the error after running the job. Because in Jenkins we need to setup environment difference like the machine you run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but I think it's matlab problem.Because console output of Jenkins could work normally.